# How to download a file from private file system

Tags: 7

I need a function in my module for users to download a file from a private filesystem.

```
$file : "private://sample.csv"
```

Which function should be used, `file_download()`, or  `file_transfer()`?

```
function file_download_page() {
  $file = "private://sample.csv";
  //code for downloading $file
}
```

Please provide sample code.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to call [file_create_url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_create_url/7).

It will return an URL that will go through Drupal which will then check the appropriate permiss (if you need custom checks, you need to implement hook_file_download)

Comment: For private downloads need file_create_url() and hook_file_download().
This works well.

Answer (score 1):

I use hook_file_download_access:

```
/**
 * Implement hook_file_download_access().
 */
function YOURMODULENAME_file_download_access($file_item, $entity_type, $entity) {
  global $user;
  return (in_array('hr', $user->roles) || in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [DownloadFile](https://www.drupal.org/project/download_file) you can download the file. I am using this module